# how to sort all levels of a Python OrderedDict

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort all levels of a Python ordered dictionary by the key string length, from longest to shortest. In my mind this means converting this:

```
{
    "Scientology": {
        "source": "LRH",
        "scilon 1": {
            "name": "John Travolta",
            "OT level": 5,
            "wall of fire": True
        },
        "scilon 2": {
            "name": "Tom Cruise",
            "OT level": 6,
            "wall of fire": True
        }
    }
}
```

to this:

```
{
    "Scientology": {
        "scilon 1": {
            "wall of fire": True,
            "OT level": 5,
            "name": "John Travolta"
        },
        "scilon 2": {
            "wall of fire": True,
            "OT level": 6,
            "name": "Tom Cruise"
        },
        "source": "LRH",
    }
}
```

At present, here is the code that I have:

```
dictionary1 = {
    "Scientology": {
        "source": "LRH",
        "scilon 1": {
            "name": "John Travolta",
            "OT level": 5,
            "wall of fire": True
        },
        "scilon 2": {
            "name": "Tom Cruise",
            "OT level": 6,
            "wall of fire": True
        }
    }
}

from collections import OrderedDict
print(OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary1.items(), key = lambda t: len(t[0]))))
```

This produces the following output:

```
OrderedDict([('Scientology', {'scilon 2': {'OT level': 6, 'name': 'Tom Cruise', 'wall of fire': True}, 'source': 'LRH', 'scilon 1': {'OT level': 5, 'name': 'John Travolta', 'wall of fire': True}})])
```

This does not appear to be sorted as I want. How could I sort the ordered dictionary in the manner I describe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like recursion is the best way to go if you want to sort all the items:

```
def _sort_fn(key_value_pair):
    key, value = key_value_pair
    # negative len -- Longer keys will show up first.
    # also add `key` to the tuple as keys with same length get sorted lexicographically.
    return -len(key), key

def sort_dict(d):
    new_dict = collections.OrderedDict()
    for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=_sort_fn):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            new_dict[k] = sort_dict(v)
        else:
            new_dict[k] = v
    return new_dict
```

Using this on your input:

```
>>> import json  # pprint doesn't handled OrderedDict :-(
>>> print json.dumps(sort_dict(dictionary1), indent=4)
{
    "Scientology": {
        "scilon 1": {
            "wall of fire": true, 
            "OT level": 5, 
            "name": "John Travolta"
        }, 
        "scilon 2": {
            "wall of fire": true, 
            "OT level": 6, 
            "name": "Tom Cruise"
        }, 
        "source": "LRH"
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is great. The recursive approach makes sense. Thank you very much for your help!